# Upgraded Android Studio - Project no longer builds gradle build tools version

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies, gradle

I have just upgraded my Android Studio but when I try to build/compile the project, I get the following error:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':libraries:facebook:preBuild'.

> Build Tools Revision 19.0.0+ is required.`

My gradle looks like this:

**Dependencies**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
```

**Android**

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
```

SDK Manager:

[image]

As you can see, I have installed pretty much every Android SDK Build-tools version. yet still, the error persists.

Any ideas?

**Update**
**Dependies** - which is at the bottom of the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
    compile files('libs/TestFlightLib.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/svg-android.jar')
}
```

I tried changing the support version to 19.0.+ but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong Gradle. The error specified that the error is coming from the "Facebook" gradle and not the gradle which belongs to the app. Each library has it's own gradle. So, the facebook's gradle's `builTolsVersion` was 18.0.0 instead of `19.0.0`.

Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking your project-> Android Tools->Add Support Library-> select Android Support Library, revision 19, click on Accept Licence and Install.

Comment: Oh, you use Android Studio.Than download the latest android-support-v4.jar and add it in your libs folder if you have one. Or find it in your project and replace the old jar with the new one, it should work. You should have that jar somewhere where you downloaded the SDK.

Comment: Fixed it! I was changing the Gradle in the mother project but the error was pointing to the facebook gradle! Which indeed, did not specify 19.0.0. DUH!

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate caches / restart , it fixed this like this after updated AS.

File-> Invalidate caches/restart -> Invalidate And restart.

Answer (score 0):

The file `<YourProject>/app/build.graddle` should be changed to match version of the files you have in the SDK Manager (green icon of the robot with arrow pointing down - just under Help menu). You have two options:
1) download the version you need (in SDK Manager) for which Android Studio shows links to click on them to download proper version)
2) modify the file above to match version(s) of the files you have in your SDK Manager (ie probably version numbers matching your updated-to-latest-greatest-version)
Then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fix this problem was by pasting the code, into the android of your graddle file

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```